# Is it necessary to defer deleting an object in the following multi-thread stack?

Tags: c++, multithreading

The following code from Listing 7.3 of *C++ Concurrency in Action*:

```cpp
template<typename T> 
class lock_free_stack { 
private:
    struct node { 
        std::shared_ptr<T> data; 
        node* next; 
        node(T const& data_): data(std::make_shared<T>(data_)) {} 
    }; 
    std::atomic<node*> head;

public:
    void push(T const& data) { 
        node* const new_node = new node(data); 
        new_node->next = head.load(); 
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node->next, new_node)); 
    } 
    std::shared_ptr<T> pop() { 
        node* old_head = head.load(); 
        while(old_head 
            && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next)); 
        
        auto res = old_head ? old_head->data : std::shared_ptr<T>();
        if (old_head)
            delete old_head;
        return res;
    }
};
```

The only modification is that I delete `old_head` right after retrieving the data. The author Anthony Williams says in subsection 7.2.2 (Page 214) that it's not safe to delete `old_head` at this point when multiple threads calling `pop` at the same time. I'm wondering why that's the case.

In my opinion, the while loop `while(old_head && !head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next));` ensures that there will not be two threads in which `old_head` points to the same node after the while loop. In other words, if both Thread A and Thread B finish the while loop, `old_head` in Thread A must point to a different node than the one `old_head` in Thread B points to. If both `old_head`s in Thread A and Thread B point to the same node, then at least one of them is still at the point before the `while` loop.

Let's say Thread B finishes the while loop first while Thread A is still before the while loop. Assume Thread B deletes the node before Thread A proceeds. The question becomes if this causes undefined behavior for Thread A. In the first iteration of the while loop, because of Thread B, `old_head` in Thread A is deleted and `head` points to a different location than `old_head`. Therefore, `head.compare_exchange_weak(old_head, old_head->next)` will load `head` to `old_head` and return false. Because `old_next->next` is not used by now, there will not be any problem. I verify this using the following code

```cpp
struct Node {
    int v;
    Node* next;
};


int main() {
    std::atomic head = new Node();
    auto old_node = head.load();
    old_node->next = new Node();
    head.exchange(old_node->next);
    delete old_node;
    std::cout << bool(old_node) << '\n';    // print 1
    head.compare_exchange_weak(old_node, old_node->next);
    std::cout << old_node->v << '\n';       // print 0
}
```

From my point of view, there is no problem with deleting `old_head` right after the data is retrieved because even if there is a pointer in another thread pointing to the deleted memory, it's still safe as long as we do not dereference that pointer. Am I right, or do I misunderstand something?

Comment: You really do only need two actions. Push, pop.

Comment: The code won't work as written -- it needs to call `head.load()` again in the while loops when compare_exchange_weak fails.

Comment: Hi @ChrisDodd. Why would it need to call `head.load()` in the while loop? When `compare_exchange_weak` fail, shouldn't it automatically assigned `old_head` to `head.load()`?

Answer (score 0):

The risk with deleting `old_head` when you do is that a second (or third, or ...) thread can still be in the while loop waiting to update `head`. The first thread can delete `old_head` *right before* another thread reads `old_head->next` as part of a call to `compare_exchange_weak`.

Comment: If the first thread deletes `old_head`, then in the second thread, `head` is updated by the first thread and is no longer equal to `old_head`. In that case, `compare_exchange_weak` fails and `old_head` will be reassigned to `head`. Where's the problem? You can see, in my second code block, that this is not a problem.

Comment: @Maybe There is a very small window between when thread 2 would read/load the current value of `old_head` (and gets the same value as the first thread), the first thread updates `head` and deletes `old_head`, then the second thread tries to read `old_head->next`. This potentially accesses an object that as been destroyed. The fact that the update will fail is immaterial: it is the read of the destroyed object that causes the Undefined Behavior. (Admittedly this is very rare, and will usually not crash even with the bad read.)

Comment: Hi @1201ProgramAlarm. As far as I understand, if the first thread deletes `old_head`, in thread 2, `head` and `old_head` will no longer point to the same value. Therefore, `compare_exchange_weak` will call something like `old_head=head.load()`, which does not involve `old_head->next` and is fine. In the second code block, I deleted `old_node` before `head.compare_exchange_weak(old_node, old_node->next)` and there is no error thrown. So where is the window where an error may occur? Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Maybe There is a small window _after_ the call to `head.load()` fetches the value stored in `head`, but _before_ the expression `old_head->next` is evaluated.

Comment: In that case, `old_head != head.load()` and `old_head->next` is not used. Isn't it?

Comment: When `old_head` is freed, using `old_head->next` as a parameter to the function of `head.compare_exhange_weak` is undefined behavior. You are dereferencing a dangling pointer: `old_head`.